# How to give multiple inputs in html form using for loop from python flask

Tags: python, html

This is what i tried till now but it doesn't work. How can i correct this code.
Please note that the for loop is created by using flask module in python

```py
{% for row in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{row.0}}</td>
        <td>{{row.1}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{row.0}}" name="items"></td>
        <td> <input name="it.{{row.0}}"></td>
    <tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: what does "items" contains?

Comment: If `items` is a list of lists so that `row` is a list, access its indices with `[0]`, not `.0`